# How to write out a ID and AA sequence from a SWISS PROT database file into a new file in a specific order using python?

Tags: python

I have a SWISS PROT database file that contains several SWISS PROT Files. They are copied and pasted underneath each other, so there is one SWISS prot entry after another.

I want to write the ID into another file as the header.
Immediately underneath, I want to write the amino acid sequence.

So far the program can only read one single SWISS prot entry at a time.
How can I do this for each and every SWISS Prot entry in the file?

I have managed to print out the ID header first and the amino acid sequences second.
But how do I do this sequentially for every ID and amino acid sequence?

```
bright_cyan = "\033[0;96m"
bright_yellow = "\033[0;33m"
bright_green = "\033[0;32m"
reset = "\033[0m"

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
import sys
import re  
#--------------------------------------------------------------------


def read_data(SPROT_FILE):
    
    flag = ''
 
    try:
        DNAfile = open(SPROT_FILE , 'r')
    except IOError as error:
        print(bright_cyan + "double check and see if you entered the correct filename :> ", str(error))
        sys.exit(1)
        
    
    # create a FASTA file to copy the information to and write. 
    new_outfile = open("first.fsa", 'w')
    
    amino_acid_sequence  = ''
    
    for line in DNAfile:
        #print(line, end = '')
        
        if re.match(r'ID', line):
            ID = line[5:20]     
            
        # Stateful Parsing of the amino acid sequence.  
        if re.match(r'//', line):
            flag = False
        if flag:
            amino_acid_sequence += line
        if re.match(r'SQ', line):
            flag = True
                
        # Find the modified amino acid residue. 
        if re.match(r'FT   MOD_RES', line):
            FT = line
            position_switch = ','.join(re.findall(r'\d+',FT))
            header_line = '>'+ID.strip()+" phospho:"+position_switch
            print(header_line)
            #print('>'+ID.strip()+" phospho:"+position_switch, file = new_outfile)
            
            
    # Print each amino acid sequence outside of the loop.
    amino_acid_sequence = amino_acid_sequence.replace(' ', '')
    print(amino_acid_sequence)
    
    
    # Write the amino acid sequence to the file. 
    print(amino_acid_sequence, file = new_outfile)
    
    DNAfile.close()
    new_outfile.close() 
    
    
    
files = input(bright_yellow + 'Type :> ').split()

# For each file in the input  call upon the function
for filename in files:

    read_data(filename)
```